# How to prevent second duplication check?

Tags: php

I  a have update form for account information.  Under one form i have name, username, email, company, password.  Let's say all i want to do is change my name, i still use that form and all other fields stay the same.  In the update form i have an email and username checker which make sure they aren't already taken.  So now, even if i don't change my email address or username its getting submitted to the checker code.

How can I fix it so that it doesn't prevent it if it belongs to the same person:

```
   // checks if the email is in use
  if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);
  }
  $emailcheck = $_POST['email'];
  $check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email = '$emailcheck'")
  or die(mysql_error());
  $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

  //if the name exists it gives an error
  if ($check2 != 0) {
  print("here i basically show the form once again highlighting the error)");
  die('');
   }
```

Comment: On  side note; you do use a `UNIQUE` index on the column I hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know how ur db is formatted but add username to sql should do it

```
 // checks if the email is in use
  if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $_POST['email'] = addslashes($_POST['email']);
  }
  $emailcheck = $_POST['email'];
  $check = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM accounts WHERE email = '$emailcheck' 
                        AND NOT(user='$username')")
  or die(mysql_error());
  $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

  //if the name exists it gives an error
  if ($check2 != 0) {
  print("here i basically show the form once again highlighting the error)");
  die('');
   }
```

Therefore it will look where the email is not in the row of that specific user :-)

Answer (score 1):

Store the original values in the form that is submitted, and when the form loads check for the `new value == old value`.  If they are not equal, do the check, otherwise skip it.

```
<?
   if ($_POST['oldemail'] != $_POST['newemail']) {
      //Do check here
   }
   //so on and so on
?>
```